# searching for Persian string in MySQL using laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel in order to search in products title column I use the following code:

```
$products->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->title . '%');
```

the title column is a string column and data stored in it are in Persian. Also, the database collation is UTF8_general_ci. however, when I search something some titles are found and some aren't. I need the result to find every product which contains the `$request->title` in their title columns.

can you help me?

Comment: Change `Collation UTF8_general_ci` to `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: that's a good idea.

Comment: @RameshS: good idea..!

Answer (score 1):

Change Collation `UTF8_general_ci` to `latin1_swedish_ci`

> Collations have these general characteristics:
>
> Two different character sets cannot have the same collation.
>
> Each character set has one collation that is the default collation. For example, the default collation for latin1 is latin1_swedish_ci. The output for SHOW CHARACTER SET indicates which collation is the default for each displayed character set.
>
> There is a convention for collation names: They start with the name of the character set with which they are associated, they usually include a language name, and they end with _ci (case insensitive), _cs (case sensitive), or _bin (binary).
>
> In cases where a character set has multiple collations, it might not be clear which collation is most suitable for a given application. To avoid choosing the wrong collation, it can be helpful to perform some comparisons with representative data values to make sure that a given collation sorts values the way you expect.

reference [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8006/whats-the-differences-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci-and-utf8-bina)

Comment: I did that now everything is in ??????. perhaps no way to go back. and i have no backup unfortunately

Comment: @HadiAghandeh: I think this is good way to solve this issue..!